# Photo Gallery Plugin and Touch Devices

Tags: plugins, images, mobile, slideshow

I am looking for a decent plugin that will display a slide show of images that are hosted on Flickr.  I have tried `Slickr Flickr` and and `Flickr+Highslide` (but that one seems to be missing from the WP plugins directory right now).  The issue I have with those two is they do not display the galleries properly on a mobile device.  I am using `WP Touch` to handle displaying the site on smartphones.

Is there an image plugin available that plays nice with both desktop and mobile browsers, and still has the same functioanlity of the above?

p.s.  This just for a hobby site, so the less coding the better (I'm not really a JS ninja anyway).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[fotoramajs.com](http://fotoramajs.com/)

Switch to English version in the right top corner

Comment: So far this looks like the best one to use without having to create my own plugin.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [this plugin](http://codecanyon.net/item/sublime-slider-for-wordpress/751793?WT.ac=search_item&WT.seg_1=search_item&ref=straightforward&WT.z_author=kodefoundry). It allows you to integrate Flickr and Picasa. Don't know about mobile support, you can ask it in comments. However this plugin is premium and not free.